# Help understanding this integral equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I am aware that this may be actually a trivial result, but I haven't been able to solve it.

I have the following integral equation:

$$E\left(e^{i\langle \xi,X(t)-X(s)\rangle} 1_A\right)-P(A)=\frac{\|\xi\|^2}{2}\int_s^t E\left(e^{i\langle \xi,X(u)-X(s)\rangle}1_A\right) du$$

where $P(A)$ stands for the probability of $A$ which could be regarded as a constant and $E(\cdot)$ stands for the expectation, but in this case may be regarded as a function.

Then the book states that the result is:

$$E\left(e^{i\langle \xi,X(t)-X(s)\rangle} 1_A\right)=P(A)\cdot e^{\frac{-1}{2}\|\xi\|^2(t-s) }$$

I tried working this out as a ODE, but I am not obtaining the result I need.

I guess that this something like a Volterra integral equation but I don't actually know how to solve it, so this step is not as straightforward as the book states.

Could you give me some hint on how to obtain this result?

Thanks in advance.

(by the way I am not sure which tags to use in this case, feel free to edit them)

Comment: Shouldn't that be $du$ in the integral, not $ds$? Otherwise the RH depends on $u$ and the LH does not. Also the RH uses $s$ as the variable of integration, but also as the lower limit of integration, creating some indeterminancy in the meaning of the integral.

Comment: @PaulSinclair indeed, it should be $du$. The "variable" $s$ enters in the integrand as a constant, and yes it coincides with the lower limit of integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this expression is not necessary for the problem at hand. We can rewrite it as $$y - p = k\int_s^t y(u)\,du$$
where $p, k, s$ are constant. Note that $y = p$ when $t = s$.
Differentiating gives $$y' = ky$$or $y = Ae^{kt}$ for some constant $A$. So $p = Ae^{ks}$, and $A = pe^{-ks}$. Plugging that back in, $$y = pe^{k(t-s)}$$ Substituting back in the various expressions I simplified, $$E\left(e^{i\langle \xi,X(t)-X(s)\rangle} 1_A\right) = P(A)e^{\|\xi\|^2(t - s)/2}$$

Which is *almost* the expression you are after. Note that my version has the opposite exponent than you were expecting, which corresponds to $$y = pe^{k(s-t)}$$

However, under that form, if you do the calculation,

$$\begin{align}k\int_s^t y(u)\,du &= pe^{ks}\int_s^t ke^{-ku}\,du\\&=-pe^{ks}\left.e^{-ku}\right\vert_s^t\\&=-p(e^{k(s-t)} - 1) \\&= p - y\end{align}$$
the opposite of the expression you want.

Therefore the correct answer is 
$$E\left(e^{i\langle \xi,X(t)-X(s)\rangle} 1_A\right) = P(A)e^{\|\xi\|^2(t - s)/2}$$

and the minus sign in your exponent was a mistake.

Comment: Thanks  Paul for your answer, this is precisely what I've obtained from my calculations, nonetheless the result should have a minus sign in the exponential. This is part of the proof for the Levy's characterization Theorem. The idea is to show that the random vector $X$ is Gaussian, hence on the right hand side I should obtain the characteristic function of a Gaussian.

Comment: But the math doesn't support that. Something else is going in. Possibly the formula (at least as given here) has an error - say $s, t$ swapped somewhere, or a missing sign.